# Showing mysql error for DB class in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

this example code that works with database:

```
    $status = DB::table('post')->where('id', 2)->update([
        'title' => 'new title',
        'content' => 'new content'
    ]);
```

think `$status = false` means there was an problem in updating action. How can I show mysql error for DB class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Laravel's QueryException:

use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;

```
try {
    $status = DB::table('post')->where('id', 2)->update([
        'title' => 'new title',
        'content' => 'new content'
    ]);
} catch (QueryException $e) {
   //var_dump($e->getMessage())
   \Log::error('QueryException: ' . $e->getMessage())   
}
```

***UPDATE:***
Why laravel throw QueryException when something wrong happened with SQL executing.  See this Logic in laravel's source code.

#### Class: \Illuminate\Database\Connection

```
/**
 * Run a SQL statement and log its execution context.
 *
 * @param  string    $query
 * @param  array     $bindings
 * @param  \Closure  $callback
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Database\QueryException
 */
protected function run($query, $bindings, Closure $callback)
{
    $this->reconnectIfMissingConnection();

    $start = microtime(true);
    try {
        $result = $this->runQueryCallback($query, $bindings, $callback);
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
        $result = $this->handleQueryException(
            $e, $query, $bindings, $callback
        );
    }
    ......
}
```

Comment: OP says `$status = false`, so the query was executed.

Comment: Mahdi, please explain how exactly this helped you and why did you have an exception.

Comment: Kevin, the question was addressed to Mahdi. He said that `$status = false`.

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood .